# Image based on base64 in titanium appcelerator view

Tags: titanium, base64, titanium-alloy

I want to put an image from SQLite but the code below does't work:

```
var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            image:services.fieldByName('image')
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

do this to convert the blob to a string before saving it

```
var stringToSaveInDatabase = Ti.Utils.base64encode(thumbBlob).toString();
```

when you are ready to add it to a view, do this

```
var imageBlob = Ti.Utils.base64decode(stringRetrievedFromDatabase);
Ti.UI.createImageView({ image:imageBlob });
```

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Utils-method-base64encode

Comment: thanks for your answer mi problem is that I get data form API, 
the api has the image stored in a MYSQL db,